# Scala what means the place older _ in var declaration

Tags: scala

I was reading the guide to use Junit with scala on this [site](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-junit-testing-with-scala) 
And there is line of code I don't understand in the code lines I copy pasted at the end of this message.

The code line is :

```
var pizza: Pizza = _
```

I know that the place holder is used in the pattern matching to say "if it's anything else do this". But I don't understand what it means hear.

Can someone explain ?

```
package com.acme.pizza

import org.junit.Test
import junit.framework.TestCase
import org.junit.Assert._
class PizzaTests extends TestCase {

  var pizza: Pizza = _

  override def setUp {
    pizza = new Pizza
  }

  def testOneTopping {
    pizza.addTopping(Topping("green olives"))
    assertEquals(pizza.getToppings.size, 1)
  }

  def testAddingAndRemovingToppings {
    pizza.addTopping(Topping("green olives"))
    pizza.removeTopping(Topping("green olives"))
    assertEquals(pizza.getToppings.size, 0)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means assign default value to it.
For example,

```
scala> var num:Int = _
num: Int = 0

scala> var name:String = _
name: String = null
```

When i declare an integer value,it assigns 0 as default value to it and null as default value to a string.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it initializes the variable with the default value depending on its type. You can find more details in [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html) under `4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions`.

Here are the default values:

```
 default  type T
 0        Int or one of its subrange types
 0L       Long
 0.0f     Float
 0.0d     Double
 false    Boolean
 ()       Unit
 null     all other types
```